# Is there an easy way to take derivative of $y = 7 + (8x-5)^6$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was taking the derivative of $y = 7 + (8x-5)^6$. I was trying with this method:

$$\frac{(7+(8(x+h)-5)^6) - (7+(8x-5)^6)}{h}$$

But with that power of 6, it would be very difficult to calculate derivative like this. Which method can i  use to take derivative of this function?

Comment: In the meantime, you can algebraically do $7-7=0$. After $8x-5=u$.

Comment: Just use the properties of the derivative. $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ , $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ and $(ax+b)'=a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=8x-5$. Then $y=7+z^6$ and you have

$\frac {dy}{dz} = 6z^5 \\ \frac {dz}{dx} = 8$

and you can use the chain rule to find $\frac {dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{(7+(8(x+h)-5)^6) - (7+(8x-5)^6)}{h}=\frac{(8(x+h)-5)^6 -(8x-5)^6}{h}$$$$=\frac{(8x-5+8h)^6-(8x-5)^6 }{h}=\frac{(u+8h)^6-u^6}{h}$$
with $u=8x-5$.

If you expand you can obtained

$$=\frac{8h\left(2u+8h\right)\left(\left(u+8h\right)^2-u\left(u+8h\right)+u^2\right)\left(\left(u+8h\right)^2+u\left(u+8h\right)+u^2\right)}{h}$$
i.e
$$=8\left(2u+8h\right)\left(\left(u+8h\right)^2-u\left(u+8h\right)+u^2\right)\left(\left(u+8h\right)^2+u\left(u+8h\right)+u^2\right)$$
and for $h\to 0$,

$$8\cdot 2u \cdot u^2 \cdot 3u^2=48u^5=48(8x-5)^5$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $y = 7 + (8x-5)^6$. Set $u = 8x - 5$. So $\dfrac{du}{dx} = 8$, and since $y = 7 + u^6$, we get $\dfrac{dy}{du} = 6u^5$. Using chain rule, note that $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx} = 6u^5 \cdot 8 = 48(8x - 5)^5$